# Axios request returns promise instead of the data itself

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a function that checks the existence and validity of a token and makes a new request to get a new token if the token does not exists or is expired.
But the function always returns a promise instead of the data, and can not use it further.

```
const checkToken = (token) => {
    if (!token || !(token.hasOwnProperty('expiry') && Object.prototype.toString.call(token.expiry) === '[object Date]') && !isExpired(token.expiry)) {
        token =  axios(getOptions()).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data.expires_in);
        let today = new Date();
        let expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 1000*(resp.data.expires_in));
        return ({
          'token': resp.data.access_token,
          'expiry': expiry
      });
      });
    return token;  
  }
  return token;
}
```

checkToken is consumed like so:

```
const axios = require('axios');
let token;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
console.log(token);
console.log(event);
  token = checkToken(token);
  let options = getReqOptions(event,token);
  
  console.log(options)
   return options
};
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: how do you call checkToken, or in other words, what consumes your promise?

Comment: An `axios()` call returns a promise.  That's how it works.  You can use either `await` or `.then()` with that promise to get the value.  And, you cannot directly return an asynchronously retrieved value from any Javascript function (because the function will return long before the asynchronous value is ready).  Instead, you have to use a callback, an event or a promise to communicate back the asynchronously retrieved value.

Comment: @jfriend00 but I have a .then attached to axios call. Axios(getOptions()).then ....

Comment: @rags2riches I have edited my original question and have added the consumer.

Comment: That allows you to use the resolved value from the axios call's promise inside the `.then()` handler, but your function has already long since returned when the `.then()` handler is called so you can't return that value directly from your function. The best you can do is return the promise and let the caller use `await` or `.then()` on the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `Axios` return a `promise` but you're again returning a promise using [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). You're using `then` value for `token`. That's why you're seeing `token` as a promise. You can simply use `async/await` to get same(more readable).

```
const checkToken = async (token) => {
  if (!token || !(token.hasOwnProperty('expiry') && Object.prototype.toString.call(token.expiry) === '[object Date]') && !isExpired(token.expiry)) {
    try {
      const reponse = await axios(getOptions())
      console.log(reponse.data.expires_in);
      const expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 1000 * (reponse.data.expires_in));
      return {
        token: resp.data.access_token,
        expiry
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Error while getting token ', err)
      // handle error here if any
    }
  }
  return token
}
```

```
const axios = require('axios');
let token;

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(token);
  console.log(event);
  try {
    token = await checkToken(token);
    let options = getReqOptions(event, token);
    console.log(options)
    return options
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```